# Formatting numerical data

Tags: discussion

When formatting numerical data, should it be:

$15~\mathrm{kg}$

`$15~\mathrm{kg}$`

or

15 $\mathrm{kg}$

`15 $\mathrm{kg}$`

For the sake of consistency, I strongly feel that it should be one or the other, but not both (but in the end I guess it's not my choice to make).

Comment: The first one is the better one in my opinion, in the other one the unit might break the line.

Comment: I'm unclear on why 15 kg, without unnecessary formatting, is not the preferred choice.  I personally find the oversized, arbitrarily bolded text difficult to read.

Comment: For current answers addressing this question please view the [community wiki on formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3045/23561).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with the comments of Martin and Molx on that the fonts of the value and the unit should match.

If one takes a closer look at the output of expressions using the `siunitx` package, which isn't available here, one realizes that the gap between the number and the unit is **smaller** than a standard (protected) space.

The optical equivalent to

`\SI[group-digits=false]{8.3146621}{\joule\per\mol\per\kelvin}` in MathJax is `$8.3146621\,\mathrm{J\,mol^{-1}\,K{^{-1}}}$`, and yields

$8.3146621\,\mathrm{J\,mol^{-1}\,K{^{-1}}}$

Comment: May I still use the protected space please? Since the siunitx package is far from being implemented, I find it much easier to just type the tilde. I also like it, when it harmonises [with this discussion](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945).

Comment: What's the difference between `$8.1\ \mathrm{g}$`,  `$8.1~\mathrm{g}$` and `$8.1\, \mathrm{g}$`? The first two seem to yield identical results, while the third gives a smaller space. Does it have to do with being *protected*? What is that, by the way?

Comment: @Molx You're right! `\,` does yield a smaller space,  `\~` gives a space at which no line break can happen. That's called a protected space.

Comment: @Martin Yes, please :-) I'm not planning to to go on an edit spree to convert spaces in MathJax expressions with a script ;-) Having `siunitx` would nice, but since it isn't available, we live with what we have. And actually, that is already quite a lot, as compared to other sites.